# Tomcat hangs when shutting down (daemon) threads (ScheduledExecutorService)

Tags: java, tomcat, scheduledexecutorservice, application-shutdown

In my webapp i have classes that used to extend thread class with a run() routine. I had problems with them when shutting down tomcat so replaced the thread implementations with a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

However it still does not work: When shutting down tomcat in my eclipse console there are logging statements like this:

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [Appname] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

After a timeout i always get a message, that tomcat is not responding and i have to terminate it manually.

I am starting those in an init() and destroy() method of my servlet like this:

```
public void init() throws ServletException
    {
            worker = new worker();
            worker.schedule();
    }


    public void destroy()
    {
            worker.shutdownTimer();
            worker = null;
    }
```

The methods look like this:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService mScheduler = null;

public void schedule()
    {
        scheduler = getScheduleService();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                //...things to do in the routine
            }
        }, 
        1,     //start after 1 second
        10,    //wait 10 seconds 
        TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

private ScheduledExecutorService getScheduleService()
    {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, new ThreadFactory()
        {
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(r);
                // allow the JVM to kill the scheduled task
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                return thread;
            }
        });
        return scheduler;
    }

    public void shutdownTimer()
    {
        if (scheduler != null)
            scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }
```

In my debugger i can see that the executorservice has started following thread:

```
Daemon Thread [Timer-0] Running
Thread [pool-3-thread-1] Running
```

Why does the ExecutorService start a normal threadpool?

And when does the jvm still have problem closing those threads when i'm explicitly telling it to shut them down in my servlet?